# List to string with one space

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume that i have a list x = ["123" , "100" , "200"] , i want to convert it to a single string like "123 100 200" in same order and there is a one space between numbers.

Comment: *"i want to convert it to a single string ..."* and what is stopping you? You can do that.

Comment: Hi, posts of the type “Show me how to solve this coding problem" are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). It’s expected that you to first make an [honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: You can try `' '.join(x)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: This site is English only. Please read the rules before posting. Also, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question and improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> x = ["123" , "100" , "200"] 
>>> ' '.join(x)
'123 100 200'
>>>
```